# Overwrite/Lock Values in Power Query Excel

Tags: sql, excel, database, export-to-excel, powerquery

I have a excel sheet that is pulling from an external db via a power query and I was trying to find out if there is a way to edit cells in the spreadsheet and then prevent the power query from overwriting those values when you do a refresh. Is there a way to lock cells and prevent a refresh from changing those locked values? I want to be able to directly change cells in excel and then lock those cells from changing or refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps.  Lets you save values as a comment column, but can be used for something similar

http://exceleratorbi.com.au/self-referencing-tables-power-query/